# How to implement paypal recurring payment in codeigniter using api

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, recurring-billing

I am new in codeigniter. I want to implement paypal recurring payment with using api. How is it possible ?
Can anybodody please tell me in details or step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi first you need to download the library of paypal, then create your account
in your controller use it like

```
        $config['business']             = 'username@domain.com';
        $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
        $config['return']               = 'sucess.php';
        $config['cancel_return']        = 'shopping.php';
        $config['notify_url']           = 'process_payment.php'; //IPN Post
        $config['production']           = TRUE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox
        //$config['discount_rate_cart']     = 20; //This means 20% discount
        $config["invoice"]              = 'xxxxxx'; //The invoice id
        $config["currency_code"]        = 'EUA';
        $config["cpp_cart_border_color"]= '7D88B6 ';

        $this->load->library('paypal',$config);

        #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);

        $this->paypal->add('T-shirt',2.99,6); //First item
        $this->paypal->add('Pants',40);       //Second item
        $this->paypal->add('Blowse',10,10,'B-199-26'); //Third item with code

        $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
```

Comment: Can you please give me the link to download the library for codeigniter?